# Laravel can't access database

Tags: heroku

I cvurrently have a laravel application running on heroku, the issue here is, I keep getting the error that I can't connect to the database: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'ec2-54-74-209-179.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)`. Now the host is wrong here, the environment files are TOTALLY different (except for the username) then what the error gives....

How can I resolve this issue?

I've tried to use the DB_URL env, but that gives the same result...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the .env correctly on what's running on their server?
You can see all your projects in laravel at TOOLS->DEPLOYEMNT->CONFIGURATIONS
add all the info and connect to the remote project. I did the same and changed the .env directly there.

and of course you have to clean all the cache cause even if you change the .env it will not work until you'll clear it

```
 php artisan cache:clear;
 php artisan config:clear;
 php artisan route:clear;
```

Obviously this need to be executed on the project on heroku or aws (as it appears from the Error)

Comment: Yes, I've set all the vriables correct, when I try to execute the artisan codes, I get the same error thrown... I neither have any possibility to contact the support service of heroku...

Comment: do the project works on local?
and you can access the server/ instance through ftp/ putty?

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, the host did not allow remote connections, I've fixed it by using a different host...